# Secure connection strings to a Azure MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

Forgive me, because I'm playing monkey-in-the-middle here.

I write data migration systems. A customer has their data in a private MSSQL DB that is managed by a 3rd party. The 3rd party agreed to send backups (using litespeed) on a schedule so we can get a local copy of the data.

The customer's IT guy has been tasked with providing a DB and access via a connection string for our project. Originally, he spun up a Azure VM running SQL. Normally we would suggest SSPI for security, allowing the AD to handle access and avoiding user/pass in the connection string.

The problem is that you cannot connect an Azure VM to your Active Directory. When he asked how to do so, MS's Azure team suggested another solution using an SaaS SQL server and uploading the DB as a Data Tier app. That does allow it to use their AD, but requires a hopelessly complex 7-step restore process.

I suspect there is a better solution, but I am not familiar enough with MSSQL security models, or Azure, to know the proper lingo. Suggestions? It doesn't have to be AD based.

Comment: This depends on a lot of situation specific details here. You *can* connect an Azure VM to Active Directory (though it may still not be reasonable for other reasons) and MS is probably trying to push their cloud products. Its not clear how you're connecting to the database (is this an application? user logging in manually? other?) or why them giving you a SQL Login with password is not an option.

Comment: [Managing secrets for an application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/features-api/best-practices-for-deploying-passwords-and-other-sensitive-data-to-aspnet-and-azure#da) is a solidly tread pattern and may be better off for SO than this SE site if that is what your need is.

Comment: @LowlyDBA - I later learned there is a bit of data I was missing. The AD in this case is not an AD, but a Cloud AD of some sort. It cannot be connected to the VM. Apparently it can be connected to an MI. It's good that all of this is so simple and obvious!